# Filter table with JS and have a "No Results Found"

Tags: javascript, php

I have been trying to work out how to incorporate a if else statement to the following code to return a add row to the table is results = 0 with a message that says "No Results Found".
My code is:

```
//Function for searching products
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#productInput").on("keyup", function() {
        let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#productTable tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });

    });
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you toggle all the matching rows, count the number of visible rows. If it's 0, add the row that says nothing found.

`filter()` returns the set of elements that match the condition. You're not returning anything from the callback function, so you should use `.each()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#productInput").on("keyup", function() {
    let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#productTable tr.notfound").remove(); // remove extra row if we added it during previous filter
    $("#productTable tr").each(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(value));
    })
    if ($("#productTable tr:visible").length == 0) {
      $("#productTable").append("<tr class='notfound'><td>No results found</td></tr>");
    }
  });
});
```